# How do I resolve an unknown type error occurring in a minno script accessed via url?

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to use the minno framework to create a implicit association test and I keep running into the following error when i try start my implicit association test:

```
Error: Unknown task type: "iat"
    at i.get (https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/minnojs/minno-quest@0.3/dist/pi-minno.js:38:82085)
    at https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/minnojs/minno-quest@0.3/dist/pi-minno.js:38:82493
    at link (https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/minnojs/minno-quest@0.3/dist/pi-minno.js:38:83257)
    at https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/minnojs/minno-quest@0.3/dist/pi-minno.js:16:37982
    at D (https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/minnojs/minno-quest@0.3/dist/pi-minno.js:16:34553)
    at https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/minnojs/minno-quest@0.3/dist/pi-minno.js:16:28975
    at https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/minnojs/minno-quest@0.3/dist/pi-minno.js:16:28270
    at https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/minnojs/minno-quest@0.3/dist/pi-minno.js:16:29114
    at D.c (https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/minnojs/minno-quest@0.3/dist/pi-minno.js:16:34059)
    at n.i.enter (https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/minnojs/minno-quest@0.3/dist/pi-minno.js:56:121174) <div pi-task="task" class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope">
```

I am using the iat extension found [here](https://app-prod-03.implicit.harvard.edu/implicit/common/all/js/pip/piscripts/ydocs/dist/index.html) and the instructions outlined in the Github repository readme found [here](https://github.com/minnojs/simple-minno-server).

Comment: First step: don't use the minified version of the library.

Comment: What do you mean by that ?

Comment: The names in the stack trace look like minified function names, which are meaningless. Use the non-minified version of the library so that when you're using the JavaScript debugger you get useful variable and function names.

Comment: The names aren't minified functions names. The framework used just happens to be called minno

Comment: `D.c` and `n.i` looks minified

Comment: I used the following to call the script: `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/minnojs/minno-quest@0.3/dist/pi-minno.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` . How can I insure I don't call the minified version?

Comment: Looks like they only uploaded a minified version to the CDN. If you want to debug it, you need to find the original source and download that to your server, instead of using the CDN.